In iOS, is Location Push Service Extension considered a daemon?
My app was jettisoned for the reason of "highwater".
As per Apple docs,

highwater: A system daemon exceeded its highest-expected memory
footprint.

I am suspecting, that my LPSE is suddenly running out of memory. And this would make sense to be the cause, but I just wish there was a confirmation of a sort: can Location Push Service Extension be considered a daemon in this context?
